# Handle Exception by sending app to login screen ios

Tags: ios, swift

I want to send an application to login screen when a crash occurs.

**Crash Code** -

```
 let array = [String]()
_ = array[2]  // After this application crashes
```

**Put this code in didFinishLaunchMethod to Catch crash**

```
 NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
                print(exception)
                print(exception.callStackSymbols)
//I can get exception here but I want to send my application to login screen
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean when relaunching the app after it crashes? When the app crashes you're basically done

Comment: That's not how it works. `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` allows you to perform last-minute logging before the program terminates. The program will not continue after that.

Comment: I want to send app to first view controller when an exception occurs

Comment: You can't. The app will stop running after the exception handler returns, period.

Comment: and how can I get log of nil pointer exceptions